# Most effective method of communicating between two android app installations

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, pubnub

I am writing an android app that currently uses Parse.com and PubNub together. The app uses PubNub to communicate between any two installations. The app will only ever need a 1-on-1 communication. It is not chat, however. One installation would send a boolean (among other values) across PubNub to another installation which picks it up and runs certain methods depending on what values were sent. It then sends some other value back across to the first install, which responds to the certain values itself (all of which is not seen by the user).

The above is the only thing that I use PubNub for. I have recently been looking into Parse Push Notifications and can see that you can send JSON data along with the push, to be interpreted by the receiving install. It it also apparently possible to make the notifications "silent", which is something that I would likely take advantage of.

Is there anything wrong with removing PubNub altogether and just relying on Parse for this little back-and-forth between my apps?

Comment: yes i mean between two different devices. I understand that PubNub is realtime messaging, but my question was if it is better to just use Parse's push notifications for my purposes, since it would make everything a lot easier (not to mention cheaper) to just use one service like Parse. I am only using PubNub to communicate in the background between the two devices, which apparently can be done by sending a "silent" push and interacting with the JSON data sent along with it.

Comment: ^Very nicely worded. It is obvious you work for PubNub. I appreciate your answer but I would like to hear some people on more of a third-party perspective.

Comment: As it stands now my app already has PubNub working for said communication behind the apps, and the mobile push available from PubNub I wasn't aware of before, so I will go and check that out and see if it is something I would be interested in using.

Comment: Removed my comments in favor of an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Realtime Messaging with Mobile Push Fallback

Parse Push *is* mobile push notifications (APNS and GCM). So if you want/need realtime messaging, use PubNub with [mobile push as fallback](https://www.pubnub.com/products/mobile-push/) and continue to use Parse as your BaaS.

If you just need mobile push and you are already using Parse, then Parse Push should be your best option (for simplicity and economic reasons).

[This is a good place to get started with learning](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call) about PubNub's mobile push gateway.

To get full details on mobile push notification setup, configuration and implementation with PubNub, visit the SDK docs for the platform you are targeting: [iOS](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4), [Android](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/mobile-gateway), [Phonegap](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/phonegap-javascript/mobile-gateway), [Xamarin.iOS](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/xamarin-ios-c-sharp/mobile-gateway), [Xamarin.Android](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/xamarin-android-c-sharp/mobile-gateway), or one of [the other 70+ SDKs](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/).